# How to simulate "GoSub / Return" in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Sorry - I'm very now to PowerShell.

I'd like to iterate a variable (e.g., $Var) and each time $Var is (re)set, I want to execute a common block of code, then return.

In VB I could use GoSub / Return. It might look something like this:

> $Var = "first"
>
> GoSub BlockOfCode
>
> $Var = "second"
>
> GoSub BlockOfCode
>
> $Var = "third"
>
> GoSub BlockOfCode

>

> :*BlockOfCode*
>
> Do this
>
> Then do that
>
> Then do another thing
>
> Return

What's the best way to accomplish this in PowerShell? Preferably, I'd like to avoid having to define an array -(e.g. $Var1, $Var2, $Var3, ...) and looping through it with For Each.

Any suggestions you can provide would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [about Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions) and [related topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7#see-also)

Answer (score 0):

Use a function call. (BTW, bad example calling gosub, but I couldn't resist

```
Function GoSub {
   $var = Args[0]
   <Block of Code that uses $Var>
 }


$Var = "first"
GoSub $Var
$Var = "second"
GoSub $Var
$Var = "third"
Gosub $Var
```

Comment: Thank you Slackr! LOL
I just discovered this, and came here to update the question. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Slackr. I did accept your solution, but apparently I don't have enough Reputation Points for it to show. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just tested this, and received error message:

"Args[0] : The term 'Args[0]' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:11 ".

Here's the code:

1 Function GoSub {
2   $var = Args[0]
3   #
4   $Answer = $Var * ($Var - 1)
 5  echo $Answer
 6 }
#
$Var = 5
GoSub $Var
$Var = 10
GoSub $Var
$Var = 20
Gosub $Var

Comment: It does work with line 2 omitted

Here's the code:

1 Function GoSub {
2   ###  $var = Args[0]    ###   Remove this line
3   #
4   $Answer = $Var * ($Var - 1)
5   echo $Answer
6  }
7  #
8  $Var = 5
9  GoSub $Var
10 $Var = 10
11 GoSub $Var
12 $Var = 20
13 Gosub $Var